# Postgres JSONB datatype - How to extract data from JSON (of type JsonB) field of postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

*Hello Friends,*
I need a help to solve the following issue,

I have set of record into my postgres db table, where table has `JSONB` type field.

`JSONB` type column contains following `JSON`,

**Record#1 :-**

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "audience": [
    {
      "name": "Person1",
      "email": "test1@mail.com",
      "country": "UK",
      "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
      "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person2",
      "email": "test2@mail.com",
      "country": "UK",
      "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
      "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Record#2:-**

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "audience": [
    {
      "name": "Person3",
      "email": "test3@mail.com",
      "country": "UK",
      "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
      "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
    },
    {
      "name": "Person4",
      "email": "test4@mail.com",
      "country": "UK",
      "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
      "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Result (Get All Audience) :-**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Person1",
    "email": "test1@mail.com",
    "country": "UK",
    "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
    "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person2",
    "email": "test2@mail.com",
    "country": "UK",
    "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
    "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person3",
    "email": "test3@mail.com",
    "country": "UK",
    "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
    "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person4",
    "email": "test4@mail.com",
    "country": "UK",
    "primaryNumber": "+1234567890",
    "secondaryNumber": "+1234567890"
  }
]
```

Can Anyone **help me to design** a query either `native query` or through `spring-data-jpa` ?

*I appreciate really if anyone who can help me to carry out from this situation!*

Comment: this could help: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: @Tryph I tried to solve it first. but looks I am unable to decide such a query as per the expectation. that's why I request openly who can help me. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract `'audience'` array elements of each row with `jsonb_array_elements()` and aggregate them to a single json object with `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select jsonb_agg(value)
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_data->'audience')
```

[Working example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/TURL78660)